# Why bower install polymer with "Polymer/" prefix and version number?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

The [Polymer Doc](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/getting-the-code.html) suggests to install polymer with:

```
bower install --save Polymer/polymer#^1.0.0
```

Why not just this:

```
bower install --save polymer
```

Answer (score 1):

`#^1.0.0` instructs Bower to install the latest 1.x.x version of Polymer  that doesn't increment the first non-zero leftmost number, so anything between 1.0.0 but below 2.0.0 exclusive (thanks to [zerodevx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5017988/zerodevx) for correction). If you omit that and just run `bower install --save Polymer/polymer` it will install the latest and greatest version.

The `Polymer/polymer` command instructs Bower to go to GitHub and install from the source code repository. You could potentially use the shorthand `polymer` by itself, if the Polymer team has officially registered with Bower (I'm not sure). To be safe, just go directly to the source and install via `Polymer/polymer`.

I don't think there is a reason to install 1.0.0 specifically. You should install the latest and greatest. So it's just a documentation error. I'll create a pull request to change the documentation.

Comment: Actually, the caret in `#^1.0.0` tells bower to install the latest that doesn't increment the first leftmost non-zero, so in this case anything above Polymer 1.0 but below Polymer 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Just a difference in what gets downloaded.  The former, adds an extra folder, "core-component-page".  Try it yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The number next to the element is just a version...
If your app works with a specific version you can specified like that